# iframe link redirect inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe to display an external webpage.
But when I click on any links on that page, it opens a new tab.
I want to keep the navigation in my iframe.

```
<iframe id="sr-paper-frame-1" src="http://paper.li/~/papers/1372d609-365c-4deb-9a46-977672478b33?ifrm=true&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.safetyrecalls.org%2F" width="100%" height="800" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="width:1px;min-width:100%;*width:100%;"></iframe>
```

If anyone has an idea about this, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The links in the site you're framing have a `target=_blank` attribute causing them to open in a new window. It is not possible for you to change this.